# Compile and run a C bit operation file

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am working on this bitwise operators in C program.i need to compile and run the program to check the output is working correct or not . what compiler i need to use to run and execute the program and what is the command to execute this C program:

```
enter code here

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "bitslab.h"
 int main() 
 int bitAnd(int x, int y)   
 int getByte(int x, int n)
 int logicalShift(int x, int n)
 {
 printf("bitAnd Result: %d\n", bitAnd(15,3));
 printf("getByte Result: %d\n", getByte(20,4));
 printf("logicalShift Result: %d\n", logicalShift(12,4));

 return ~((~x)|(~y)); 
 return (x>>(n<<3))&0xff; 
 return ((x >> n) & ((1 << ((~n + 1) + 32)) + ~0));
 }
```

Comment: You should probably work through [a tutorial for C programming](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming) and try make sure you can compile and run a simple “hello, world” program.  Only then, proceed to more complex examples.

Comment: @nishantjr i am working on C programming for using these operators ..when i try to run them in turbo C i am getting an error like "no value for bitAND,getByte etc" ..since it considers those bit operands as constants... i would like to know which compiler to use for running this program !! help me out ..thanks in advance

Comment: You've declared (but not implemented) the  `main`, `bitAnd` and `getByte` functions, and have three return statements inside the only one you actually implemented (`logicalShift`). Find a basic C tutorial and work through it; you're nowhere near being able to test using those operators until you can actually write code that will compile.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite for your reply ... For bitAnd and getByte ..that is the operation which i had implemented in return statement .since i was restricted not to use loops i simply implemented while return ..what kind of change i need to make it ...like i tried to find help tutorials but not able to find any !!

Comment: The first comment to your question provides a tutorial link for you. Your code declares functions, not "operations", and you have not properly implemented those functions. A tutorial will explain to you how to properly declare functions, write the implementations, and return the values, as well as how to properly call them. This is not a "write me a tutorial" site. Google `c programming tutorial` and you should be able to find many of them.

Answer (score 0):

On linux flavours use GCC to compile your program.
http://www.wikihow.com/Compile-a-C-Program-Using-the-GNU-Compiler-(GCC)

On windows you can try turbo-C or visual C++.

I guess your program is not complete and I fear it would not run properly.

Enjoy debugging and happy coding.

Comment: thanks @prasad for helping me out !!i have implemented the program but yes as you said i am getting errors ..what i need to change in making it function properly ?

Comment: paste what errors you are getting, then I may be able to help.